# take the bite out of something / someone

Tags: idioms, american-english

Question about the expression: "You should **take the bite out of him** by telling him...." meaning you should subdue him.

Does anyone know the origin of this expression? I am especially interested to find out of this is a typically American expression?

Comment: I've not heard this being applied to people, only to situations or objects (SE AmE here). When I first read it, subduing someone was not what I thought of -- something more like taking the wind out of his sails.

Answer (score 0):

Several dictionaries give a meaning similar to this:

> "take a bite out of" PHRASE informal
>
> = Reduce by a significant amount.
>
> [Oxford Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/take_a_bite_out_of)

Such definitions do not entirely explain your quotation because the man referred to is clearly not being reduced in any physical sense. However, the phrase refers to reducing some non-physical aspect of the man, such as the force of his argument, or of the threat he represents to someone.

To make up rather crude examples: he might threaten to throw you out of the house but you take the bite out of him (his threat) by telling him you are armed; he argues that women are foolish but you take the bite out of him (his argument)
by listing the many clever women.

There is also a possible original connection to the idea of an animal whose behaviour is so threatening as likely to bite. The threat may be reduced by giving food, for example.

Comment: The question asked for the origin of the phrase, not the the meaning.

Comment: As I have dealt with at the end.

Comment: I think there's a significant difference between "take **the** bite out of" and "take **a** bite out of."  See, e.g., [this ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/122021/120885).  This answer appears to conflate the two phrases.

Answer (score 0):

I used Google's N-gram viewer to analyze the usage history of "take the bite out of". I compared it to "take a bite out of" and "take a bite from", which have slightly different connotations, but are similar in formation. Here's the N-gram:
["take a bite out of,take a bite from,take the bite out of"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take%20a%20bite%20from%2Ctake%20a%20bite%20out%20of%2C%20take%20the%20bite%20out%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20bite%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20bite%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20the%20bite%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0)

It would appear that anything rising to the level of idiomatic usage is quite recent, and only applicable to "take **a** bite out of". That usage slope begins a rapid rise about 1980, which coincides with the advent of [McGruff, the crime dog, advertising campaign ("Take a bite out of crime")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McGruff_the_Crime_Dog). I don't think you'd go far wrong if you guessed that McGruff shares responsibility for the rise.

And, since McGruff is a US advertising campaign, that would make it an American expression. Although, it may have spread to international usage (I wouldn't know).

The usage "take the bite out of" may be metaphoric, or it may be quite literal. For example, taking the bite out of a hot pepper would be literal, as bite in that usage is among the accepted definitions. In contrast, the usage "I took the bite out of that boy's mean attitude!" would be a metaphor, assuming biting would not be a literal part of the situation. It does not appear in the N-gram to ever rise to the level of idiomatic usage. However, there is a good discussion on the usage of ["take a bite out of" vs "take the bite out of" on this ELL question.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122019/difference-in-the-meaning-and-the-grammar-between-take-a-bite-out-of-the-stings) (Thanks to user @RyanM for the link!)

Comment: I think there's a significant difference between "take **the** bite out of" and "take **a** bite out of."  See, e.g., [this ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/122021/120885).  This answer appears to conflate the two phrases.

Comment: @RyanM quite right! My error. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a variation of the old expression **"take the sting out of."**

> *He could easily conceive [...]that a clause might be moved to take the
> string out of it.*
>  [Cobbett's Parliamentary History of England, 1777]

> *Mr. Wordsworth [...] and a friend had been to see Coleridge, who had
> detained them by one continuous flow of talk. "How was it you called
> so early upon him ?" inquired Rogers.  "Oh," replied Wordsworth, "we
> are gong to dine with him this evening, and ――" " And," said Rogers,
> taking up the sentence, "you wanted to take the sting out of him
> beforehand."*
>  [A posthumous autobiographical fragment with notes of his
> literary friends, by Bryan Proctor (1787-1874)]